# SQL only show orders with one order row. if more rows don display anything

Tags: sql, select, count

i´m trying to search for orders with one specific article on the order row, but if there more than one row i don´t want to see any of the rows.

This is a sample of two orders where i only want to get one resault. order 9891026 has two rows and 9891025 only have one row.

```sql
    select  order_no, line_no
    from customer_order_line
    where order_no in('9891026','9891025')
```

result

| order_no | line_no |
| --- | --- |
| 9891026 | 1 |
| 9891026 | 2 |
| 9891025 | 1 |

i only want to get

| order_no | line_no |
| --- | --- |
| 9891025 | 1 |

I have don´t have a clue how to make the right query for this.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Also tag your DBMS.

Comment: @stickybit seriously?

Comment: @SalmanA: Yes, seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the single-line order numbers `order_no` (the subquery) and then select from orders with these order numbers only. Please note that a join query (though maybe harder to read) might be more efficient.

```sql
select * 
from customer_order_line 
where order_no in
(
 select order_no 
 from customer_order_line
 group by order_no 
 having count(*) = 1
) -- this is the list of single-item orders
and order_no in (9891026,9891025) -- this is the list of target orders
```

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to check if an order `exists` with a line_no greater than 1:

```
select ol.order_no, ol.line_no
from customer_order_line ol
where ol.order_no in (9891026, 9891025)
and not exists (
  select * from customer_order_line x
  where x.order_no = ol.order_no and x.line_no > 1
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I get "invalid number" when i use this query.

Comment: I got an answer on the last example, it is varchar, so i just did the same edit here (9891026, 9891025) --> ('9891026', '9891025')
Thank you! This works ass well!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can do a `GROUP BY` and use `HAVING` to make sure only one row is there.

```
select ol.order_no, min(ol.line_no)
from customer_order_line ol
where ol.order_no in ('9891026', '9891025')
group by ol.order_no
having count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I get "invalid number" when i use this query. like the first one.

Comment: @JimmyOlsson, column order_no data type? (I assumed it was integer, but perhaps it's varchar? I've edited the query anyway, so it should work now.)

Comment: Yes, now it works! Thanks!